# ssh remote command does not return

Tags: ssh

I am running `ssh somehost "service XXX restart"` and the shell hangs.

The service is nodeJS and I see `express is listening on port ...` print I made in `server.js` and that's it, it does not return to prompt, it simply hangs.

I tried nohup and & but it does not help. What else can I try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

turns out that using `-t` resolves the issue.

`ssh -t root@somehost "service XXX restart"` does not hang.

other suggestions from the comments that might resolve this:

- `node myScript.js & disown`
- `exec node myScript.js &`

Comment: This also terminates the backend process that actually hangs your command.

Comment: @AlanDuan I've used this on a webservice for years. Actually still using it.. and it works fine..

Comment: Future readers might want to try `node myScript.js & disown` or `exec node myScript.js &` in order to detach itself from current process. See more info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal).

Comment: If you're running this ssh within a script, you may have to double the -t, like `ssh -tt root@somehost "command" `. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Using `ssh -t` does not hang, but it terminates the remote process too.

What works for me is just to run the remote process in background as shown below:

```
ssh somehost /path/to/some/script augment1 augment2 &
```