# Powershell script not exiting while running via freeSSHd

Tags: powershell, ssh

I am trying to run a powershell script from a linux box using freeSSHd. I have installed and configured freeSSHd to do passwordless authentication.

When I run the ssh to execute the powershell, it is giving me the expected output but its stuck ie, I am not getting the prompt back.

`ssh me@my_windows_box 'powershell C:\Users\gkr\Desktop\my_ps_script.ps1 arg1'`

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Hard to tell, what is the script doing? What errors or messages are you seeing?

Comment: There is no error, script fetch some details about each disk which is coming as expected. I am getting the output also but I don't get the session or console back. I have to kill the process to get the console

Comment: I found a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569588/ssh-remote-command-does-not-return They are suggesting issuing the command like this: `ssh -t me@my_windows_box 'powershell C:\Users\gkr\Desktop\my_ps_script.ps1 arg1'`

Comment: This will cause the ssh to terminate forcefully ( ` Connection to my_windows_box closed.` ) after the execution, which is not fixing the root cause. I found the right way to do it. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick was to add **`-inputformat none`** switch to powershell. Found it [here](https://serverfault.com/a/541601/261891)

So the ssh command should look like this
`ssh me@my_windows_box 'powershell -inputformat none C:\Users\gkr\Desktop\my_ps_script.ps1 arg1`