# ssh remote command not executed on openBSD

Tags: ssh, openbsd, remotecommand

Trying to execute command via ssh, but I'm not receiving anything back. The server A is Solaris machine and Server B is SUSE linux with OpenBSD sshd. Checked

> 1. [ssh remote command does not return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569588/ssh-remote-command-does-not-return)
> 2. https://www.openbsd.org/papers/auug2002-ssh.pdf
> 3. https://superuser.com/questions/792070/commands-over-ssh-not-producing-output

and other sources, but can't resolve it.

The command I'm trying is (in bash):

```
    ssh -v -i .ssh/id_rsa -p1234 user2@abcdefg 'ls'
```

(tried without quotes and with double quotes as well )

And the debug info I'm receiving is :

```
    Sun_SSH_1.1.6, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090704f
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
    debug1: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to ABCDEFG [100.100.100.100] port 1234.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file ../../../.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: Logging to host: abcdefg
    debug1: Local user: user1 Remote user: user2
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_1.1.6
    debug1: use_engine is 'yes'
    debug1: pkcs11 engine initialized, now setting it as default for RSA, DSA, and symmetric ciphers
    debug1: pkcs11 engine initialization complete
    debug1: Failed to acquire GSS-API credentials for any mechanisms (No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible
Unknown code 0
)
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: Peer sent proposed langtags, ctos:
    debug1: Peer sent proposed langtags, stoc:
    debug1: We proposed langtags, ctos: i-default
    debug1: We proposed langtags, stoc: i-default
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug1: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 128/256
    debug1: bits set: 1014/2048
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug1: Host 'abcdefg' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug1: bits set: 1019/2048
    debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
    debug1: newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: set_newkeys: setting new keys for 'out' mode
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: set_newkeys: setting new keys for 'in' mode
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: done: ssh_kex2.
    debug1: send SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST
    debug1: got SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying public key: .ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149 lastkey 80b0320 hint 0
    debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
    debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey)
    debug1: SSH receive window size: 198720 B
    debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
    debug1: send channel open 0
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: ssh_session2_setup: id 0
    debug1: Sending command: ls
    debug1: channel request 0: exec
    debug1: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
    debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
    debug1: channel 0: rcvd eof
    debug1: channel 0: output open -> drain
    debug1: channel 0: obuf empty
    debug1: channel 0: close_write
    debug1: channel 0: output drain -> closed
    debug1: channel 0: rcvd close
    debug1: channel 0: close_read
    debug1: channel 0: input open -> closed
    debug1: channel 0: almost dead
    debug1: channel 0: gc: notify user
    debug1: channel 0: gc: user detached
    debug1: channel 0: send close
    debug1: channel 0: is dead
    debug1: channel 0: garbage collecting
    debug1: channel_free: channel 0: client-session, nchannels 1
    debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 0 bytes in 0.1 seconds
    debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 0.0
    debug1: Exit status 1
```

The ssh_config file on serverB looks like:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.80 2008/07/02 02:24:18 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# Configuration file set-up to meet APG43L needs.

Protocol 2
PasswordAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
################################################################################
# Access to sftp subsystem is DISABLED                                         #
# Subsystem sftp internal-sftp                                                 #
################################################################################
PermitRootLogin no
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc
PrintLastLog no
Port 1234


# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys

AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

AllowGroups group1 group2 group3
AllowUsers user2
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes4
```

EDIT:
I tried to execute the commandon the remote machine and redirect its output to remote file, but this doesn't work either. No file is created ( I can write that file in the directory if I'm on remote server). I adapted the question also.

```
ssh -v -i .ssh/id_rsa -p1234 user2@abcdefg 'ls > output.dat'
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird, certainly not your command -- similar with single quotes works for me. I get the same debug output to "debug1: Sending command: ls") so everything is authenticating fine, but you're just not getting the output I then get!

Some googling implies this variation on the command gets results

```
echo 'ls' | ssh -v -i .ssh/id_rsa -p1234 user2@abcdefg
```

https://superuser.com/questions/792070/commands-over-ssh-not-producing-output

I'm assuming you have executable rights to your home directory (be amazed if you didn't)... but assumption is the mother of all f ups, so do check you can actually ls on the actual client.

Comment: I tried to echo thing also. ( I mentioned that question/link in my "home-work done " section ;) ). I got " Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. " then. I'm really puzzled.

Comment: even using the -T option that will disable allocation of a pseudo TTY? Then yep, really puzzling

Comment: with -T option together with echo 'ls" I won't get that "Pseudo..." error, but not getting anything else either